# How to perform conditional looping using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

- I want to execute test cases using commands using PowerShell scripts.
- How many time I want to execute those tests depend upon the `$HowManyTimes` variable.
- It's possible that I get the success result before the `$HowManyTimes`
  e.g As of now I set it to 3, but what if I get the successful result in the 2nd attempt itself.
- I want to ignore that specific test case that got passed and proceed to execute the new test case.
  I have copied the output of the command in `$OutPut` variable which looks like below

  Not Imp Info

  Errors, Failures and Warnings

  Failed : UnitTestProject1.TestClass.AddTest()

  Expected: 30

  But was:  45

  Not Imp Info

  Test Run Summary

  Overall result: Failed

  Not Imp Info

Below if the script which I have written.

```
$XMLfile = 'Results.xml'
[XML]$Results = Get-Content $XMLfile
$HowManyTimes = 3 # How many time the script should run.
$TestCaseToExecute
$OutPut # Storing the result of command
$StopOperation = 0
for ($i=1; $i -le $HowManyTimes; $i++)
{
    #I am reading the xml file which can have n test cases.
    #For each loop on all the test case which are failed.
    
foreach($Result in $Results.'test-run'.'test-suite'.'test-suite'.'test-suite'.'test-suite'.'test-case' | Where-Object  {$_.result -eq "Failed"})
{   
    Write-Host "Failed Test Case -- fullname :" ($Result).fullname
    $TestCaseToExecute = ($Result).fullname
    
    Write-Host " Executing ====>" $TestCaseToExecute
    Write-Host "-----------------------------------------"
            
    $OutPut = nunit3-console.exe UnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\UnitTestProject1.dll --test=$TestCaseToExecute | Out-String
    
    if($OutPut -Like "*Overall result: Failed*"){
        Write-Host "If Block"
        continue
        
    }else{
        Write-Host "else block Stop : " 
        break
    }
    
    
}

}
```

**Please let me know what changes I need to make to achieve this.**

Comment: There's not enough here to test/dev, but it sounds like you need some variation of [Break](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break?view=powershell-7.1) and/or [continue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_continue?view=powershell-7.1) statements executed conditionally.  I'm tempted to say something like `if($OutPut -Like "*Overall result: Failed*"){ Continue }` but again not enough info to work on it.  Also, it looks like you'll never hit a successful case, because of the `Where{}`...

Comment: @Steven `Where{}` is only coming into play when I am reading the values from the XML. Once I have those values I copied that into `$Result `. Now, I have a list in `$Result` Which I am executing One by one using for each loop. If any of the list items got passes I want to stop the execution-only for that specific item.

Comment: Definitely sounds like a case for `Continue` it will immediately bring you to the next iteration of the loop. So assuming you place the `Continue` properly it is effectively skipping

Comment: I have added the `Continue` and `Break` Statements in my script. it's breaking for all the components in `$Result` what I want is for individual one

Comment: You have to make them conditional.  Add the updated code to the question...

Comment: @Steven : Updated code added. Please Let me know what changes I can do in it

Comment: Understandably I'm still not clear.  If you are using `Where{...}` to filter out successful tests, then there's be no need to later skip said successes.  However, and despite my apparently imprecise first comment, use `Continue` to skip, and set the desired `If()` condition for it.  Looking at the updated code, the break statement probably doesn't belong as that will stop processing the local loop altogether. Instead focus on tactical placement of `If(...){ ...Continue... }`, again setting the condition to your needs.